# Problem when opening RME map editor LUBUNTU

Tags: lubuntu

What is wrong? I downloaded the remeres map editor [here](http://remeresmapeditor.com/marklar.php), version
`2.1 (RME-debian-2.1.tar.gz)`

But now when I tried to open it:

```
root@ubunttu-DC8CU41:/home/ubunttu/Documentos/rme# ./rme
./rme: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread-gcc42-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
root@ubunttu-DC8CU41:/home/ubunttu/Documentos/rme#
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing that library needed by the software.

In fact, as you can see [on the packages website](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libboost&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) that version of the file is not present in Ubuntu since long time ago (not even in Precise it was there, and this is already 4 years ago).

That packaged software is 6 years old, it would take half a miracle to have it work now.
The correct way to install it now is reported in [the actual github repository](https://github.com/hjnilsson/rme/) (I copy and paste here):

> ```
> # Installing dependencies
> sudo apt-get install git libboost-system-dev libboost-thread-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev libarchive-dev 
>
> # Clone the project
> git clone git@github.com:hjnilsson/rme.git
>
> # Go to RME Folder
> cd rme
>
> # Preparing to build
> mkdir build && cd build
> cmake ..
>
> # Building
> make -j `nproc`
>
> # Running and enjoy
> ./rme
> ```